# JPA query method to find by elements in a List?

Tags: jpa

I have the following two entities (Contact and Participation, linked by a ManyToMany relation) :

```
@Entity
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;


    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Participation> participations;
}


@Entity
public class Participation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

    private Status status;
}
```

I can't figure out how to get Contacts who have a specific Participation in their list. Should I look via Contacts with a specific JPA repository method (findBy...) ? Or would i have to look via the table which was created with both Contact and Participation IDs (ManyToMany) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know JPQL and/or CriteriaAPI? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage.htm#BNBTG

Comment: No, i'm a student, and i'm kinda lost because we're working on a project with little knowledge, we spend more time on google than coding

Comment: Take this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/